# Live Preview Items Without Entry URL

Tags: live-preview

This may be a silly question or a pipe dream, but i was wondering if there is a way to have a live preview for entries without a URL. For instance i have a complicated layered slider on the homepage of a site I am building and due to it's complexity it can not simply be a field or series of fields on the homepage entry, thus i've simply created a channel called 'slides' and I include that in my homepage template.

It'd be really great if there was someway to allow live-preview to show the slides while editing, or allow editing of them while in live-preview of the homepage.

Does this capability exist or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (currently) not possible to set an Entry Template without selecting *"Entries in this section have their own URLs"* in the settings.
So to make Live Preview available on your "slides" entries, you have to register the URLs.
But if you use hidden / pseudo URLs (i.e. `hideme/{slug}`) that you don't link to and nobody knows of, this shouldn't be that bad of a workaround:

- You can check if the page is shown with Live Preview using `craft.request.isLivePreview`.
  Use this to redirect normal page views (search engines / accidential URL discoveries) to 404
  and show your slider for Live Preview requests.
- Set the Entry Template to the same file you use for your homepage or a new template file where you include the slider partial.

  ```
  {# Conditionally show slider or redirect to 404 #}
  {% if craft.request.isLivePreview %}
      {% include '_includes/slider' %}
  {% else %}
      {% redirect 404 %}
  {% endif %}
  ```
- Live Preview doesn't only work for the Entry variable any more (→ [Craft 2.3.2616 release notes](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2616)). So you can make Live Preview to
  update on changes detected on any entries referenced from the template.

  **EDIT:** Unsaved entries are not yet included in such `craft.entries` calls (→ [Brandon's comment](https://plus.google.com/101325980081569498457/posts/HNDFsLUMNw9) to my question on g+). As a workaround you could do something like this:

  _includes/slider.html:

  ```
  {# Show unsaved "slider" entry #}
  {% if not entry.id %}
      <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
  {% endif %}

  {# Go through "slider" entries #}
  {% for slide in craft.entries.section('slides') %}
      {{ slide.title }}
  {% endfor %}
  ```

<s>A dedicated field to set the template (or even multiple of them) used for Live Preview would make a nice feature request though!</s> *→ [done](https://plus.google.com/101325980081569498457/posts/7jmcW93Di16)*

Comment: Carlcs I don't see the ability to set the entry template in the settings since they do not each have their own url? Am I missing something? I'm not really understanding your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Christopher ahh right, but what about giving them an (pseudo) URL and not using it?